# Windows RDP accent and special characters

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, character-encoding, notepad

Windows 10 RDP behaviour seems to have changed post [April update](https://www.theverge.com/2018/4/30/17301142/microsoft-windows-10-april-2018-update-features-review). Same hardware, same mouse, same OS, same everything.

I'm connected to a remote session (Windows Server 2012 R2) and am experiencing this in Notepad, Notepad++, Textpad and Visual Studio Code:

Typing *Shift+'and then u* does not print **"u** and instead prints **Ü**

For example: to type

```
 $sql="update
```

I type $ s q l = (shift+') u p d a t e

Expected result:

```
 $sql="update
```

Actual result:

```
$sql=Üpdate
```

To get around this new and annoying issue I am typing shift+' shift+' (twice) to print **""** and then moving the cursor back inside the quotes to type update.

Comment: Something to do with international keyboard layouts at one end or the other ...

Comment: @DavidPostill that was my first thought and checked if the update changed my keyboard/language settings. It is set to English (United States) US Keyboard.

Comment: Hmm, RDP Advanced configuration to change the default keyboard layout?